# Error while creating and writing a file on client machine using applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

Error while creating and writing a file on client machine using applet, even i have used signed jar i am getting this error.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\a.txt write)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Main.setMessage(Main.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sign the applet with a certificate.

see [the sun Java site on signed applets](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) for a description of how and why you need to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer but,I have already signed my jar using the firefox plugin keymanager with the certificate. even then the error exists.

Answer (score 0):

May be C:\ drive needs administrator access
Most probable for windows 7  and 8